# Cucumber: undefined method error for path on visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I have a cucumber step

```
When /^I go to the Add Suggestions form$/ do
  visit new_manage_suggestions_path
end
```

and a route

```
namespace "manage" do
  resource :suggestions
end
```

rake routes outputs

```
manage_suggestions POST /manage suggestions(.:format) manage/suggestions#create
```

When I run cucumber I get

```
undefined method `suggestions_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000064a4768>:0x000000064accd8> (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

Why is cucumber trying that path?

The `new_manage_suggestions_path` works fine in my app, I have a link that uses it and that is working fine.

Comment: I know you said it works in the app, but if you run `rake routes` does it show up in that list? Also, do you need a `do` in your route? `namespace "manage" do` Just wonder if it's not really catching the namespace...

Comment: Good question, my code has the do ... end properly. I mistyped for my question. I have updated the question. I have also added my routes output.

Comment: still thinking about this, but one other question. Are you sure you want `resource` and not `resources` in your routes? With plural it would allow you to have multiple suggestions. That's the last obvious thing I would toggle to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Ah, brilliant. That was obvious, thanks! Promote to an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes definition, in order to have your app generate the correct routes, you need to switch from the singular `resource` to plural `resources` since you could potentially have multiple suggestions.

```
namespace "manage" do
  resources :suggestions
end
```

More details can be found in the Rails documentation on [singular resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources), where you can see that the singular version does not include the namespace in its path names.